# Wildfly log prints the same line twice

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, wildfly-10

When I log a message in the code the server prints twice the same message with the only difference of the date at the beginning.

I'm using the default log configuration that comes with the server Wildfly 10.

**Server.log**

```
09:43:09,122 INFO  [es.myapp.business.scheduler.boundary.Job] (default task-91) ----------INIT Job Mon Nov 20 10:05:08 CET 2017
2017-11-20 09:43:09,122 INFO  [es.myapp.business.scheduler.boundary.Job] (default task-91) ----------INIT Job Mon Nov 20 10:05:08 CET 2017
```

**Job.java**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

...
public class Job {

   protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

   public void execute() throws IOException {
        logger.info("----------INIT Job " + new Date());
   }
}
```

Wildfly **logging.properties**

```
# Note this file has been generated and will be overwritten if a
# logging subsystem has been defined in the XML configuration.


# Additional loggers to configure (the root logger is always configured)
loggers=sun.rmi,org.jboss.as.config,com.arjuna

logger.level=INFO
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE

logger.sun.rmi.level=WARN
logger.sun.rmi.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG
logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN
logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true

handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.level=INFO
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=COLOR-PATTERN
handler.CONSOLE.properties=enabled,autoFlush,target
handler.CONSOLE.enabled=true
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.target=SYSTEM_OUT

handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.fileName=/home/u24282/servers/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/log/server.log

formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n

formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n
```

Comment: Can you post your log4j.properties? It is very likely your issue is there

Comment: I don't have any log4j.properties

Comment: logging.properties from wildfly would be ok?

Comment: Yes, a common reason for this will be duplicate logging configuration. In your case with a bit different conversion pattern

Comment: This looks like there are two console handlers. Can you execute the following CLI and see what the value for `configuration` is? `/deployment=*/subsystem=logging:read-resource(recursive=true, include-runtime=true)`

Comment: I got this, 
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "result" => [],
    "rolled-back" => true
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps piping your WildFly process output to the log file?  Or, are you running in domain mode maybe?

Comment: I basically use convention wildfly configuration and standalone server. Do I have to pipe log manually or is the default option of wildfly server?